# How to recode values to na in entire dataframe for only numeric values?

Tags: r

I would like to replace some values to na in the entire dataframe for only numeric values. I tried the `na_if` solution, but it does not apply to entire dataframe.

Example data

```
data <- haven::read_spss("http://staff.bath.ac.uk/pssiw/stats2/SAQ.sav")
```

For example, I would like to recode all 4s as na.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution using `na_if`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if(., 4)))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2,571 x 23
       Q01      Q02      Q03      Q04      Q05      Q06      Q07     Q08      Q09      Q10     Q11      Q12     Q13      Q14      Q15     Q16     Q17
   <dbl+l> <dbl+lb> <dbl+lb> <dbl+lb> <dbl+lb> <dbl+lb> <dbl+lb> <dbl+l> <dbl+lb> <dbl+lb> <dbl+l> <dbl+lb> <dbl+l> <dbl+lb> <dbl+lb> <dbl+l> <dbl+l>
 1 2 [Agr~  1 [Str~ NA        2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~ 1 [Str~  1 [Str~  2 [Agr~ 1 [Str~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ 3 [Nei~ 1 [Str~
 2 1 [Str~  1 [Str~ NA        3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  5 [Str~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~ 1 [Str~  3 [Nei~ NA       3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~
 3 2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ NA        1 [Str~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ 3 [Nei~  3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~ NA        2 [Agr~ 3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~
 4 3 [Nei~  1 [Str~  1 [Str~ NA        3 [Nei~  3 [Nei~ NA       2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ NA       2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~  3 [Nei~ 3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~
 5 2 [Agr~  1 [Str~  3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~  3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~ NA        2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~ 3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~
 6 2 [Agr~  1 [Str~  3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~ NA       NA       NA       2 [Agr~ NA        3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~ NA       3 [Nei~  3 [Nei~  5 [Str~ 2 [Agr~ 3 [Nei~
 7 2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~  3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~
 8 2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~ NA        2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~  2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~
 9 3 [Nei~  3 [Nei~  1 [Str~ NA        5 [Str~  3 [Nei~  5 [Str~ 5 [Str~  3 [Nei~  3 [Nei~ 5 [Str~  5 [Str~ 5 [Str~  5 [Str~  5 [Str~ 5 [Str~ 5 [Str~
10 2 [Agr~ NA       NA        3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~  1 [Str~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~  2 [Agr~ 2 [Agr~  3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~  1 [Str~  2 [Agr~ 3 [Nei~ 2 [Agr~
# ... with 2,561 more rows, and 6 more variables: Q18 <dbl+lbl>, Q19 <dbl+lbl>, Q20 <dbl+lbl>, Q21 <dbl+lbl>, Q22 <dbl+lbl>, Q23 <dbl+lbl>
```

Note that the code above does not modify the labels of a variable. If you also want to modify those labels, consider this function

```
na_if2 <- function(x, y) {
  x[x %in% y] <- NA
  labs <- attr(x, "labels")
  attr(x, "labels")[labs %in% y] <- NA
  x
}
```

Then just replace `na_if` with `na_if2`

```
data %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if2(., c(1, 4))))
```

Comment: Great! Would it be possible to specify multiple values at once? Ex: 1, 4.

Comment: Hi @TyperWriter, try with the new `na_if2`

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
dat <- data.frame(c1 = sample(1:4, 5, T),
                  c2 = sample(1:4, 5, T),
                  c3 = sample(1:4, 5, T))
dat
  c1 c2 c3
1  4  3  3
2  4  3  3
3  4  3  4
4  3  1  2
5  4  3  3
dat[dat == 4] <- NA
dat
  c1 c2 c3
1 NA  3  3
2 NA  3  3
3 NA  3 NA
4  3  1  2
5 NA  3  3
```

Comment: Great! Would it be possible to specify multiple values at once? Ex: 1, 4.

Comment: @TyperWriter, you can use: dat[dat == 4 |dat == 1] <- NA

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `replace`

```
 library(dplyr)
 data %>% 
      mutate(across(everything(), ~replace(., . == 4, NA)))
```